# If Hitler was a far right fascist, why did he say he wanted a socialist state?

Tags: hitler, fascism, socialism

Everything I read (from seemingly reputable sources) says the Nazis, although having "Socialist" in their name – were really far right fascists. They also, apparently, worked to eradicate socialism and socialists thinking in the party.

[Britanica: Were the Nazi's socialists?](https://www.britannica.com/story/were-the-nazis-socialists)

So how come in the Speech for the Heroes' Memorial Day (21 March 1943) does Hitler say this:

"Instead, it will increasingly strive to realize, in the service of the national interest everywhere, a true Volksgemeinschaft as the highest ideal. All the more so after the war, the German National Socialist state, which pursued this goal from the beginning, will tirelessly work for the realization of a program that will ultimately lead to a complete elimination of class differences and to the creation of a **true socialist community**." *[Wikisource:HitlersSpeechForHeroes](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_Speech_for_the_Heroes%27_Memorial_Day_(21_March_1943))*

Even if this was a lie (to get popular support) – If he had already distanced himself from 'socialists', why was he still preaching 'socialism'?

Comment: This is a post on a [heavily-trolled subject](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/site-policy-for-very-heavily-trolled-topics), which means it is quite likely be closed unless it is a very good question. To that end, I worry that there are no reference links of any kind in it, and the tone could be much less apologetic toward the subject than it currently is.

Comment: Benito Mussolini, father and founder of fascism, was a socialist prior to that. These two ideologies are not mutually exclusive. Marxism (international socialism) is not only version of socialism.

Comment: My apologies, this really isn't a troll. I've noticed on Social media people totally changing what I always thought to be 'accepted' history. This was one of the points they made. I don't know enough about the situation to find the answer. I'd really appreciate someone with historical training to explain it to me. I don't know what you mean about apologetic tone. I hope my reputation on other stack accounts is enough to persuade you I am genuine.

Comment: Regarding links, they can fail over time, on SO we are encouraged to provide names - "Speech for the Heroes' Memorial Day (21 March 1943)" to prevent this from occurring.

Comment: I will also warn that while this on the surface *looks* to be a history question, its all about definitions of political terms, which are themselves quite political because people today heavily identify with and against them. Also, the reason IMHO you are seeing all this talk on social media now is *also* heavily political.  So you might get better answers on the Politics.SE (along with several very much worse answers, in my personal experience).

Comment: Granted RS - but if we assume that the 'socialism' of the time meant the same person X as person Y - even if the definition may not be the same as now - my question still stands. Why did Hitler distance himself from socialism only to promote it? Why denounce Marxism in Mein Kampf are promote socialism - from whence it derived?

Comment: @TimMottram - Bad assumption. It didn't mean the same thing to everyone (then or now for that matter). In fact what he was doing was very much about trying to redefine terms.

Comment: OK, so that's part of an answer. Feel free to provide me with some material.

Comment: @LangLangC - I've read that question / answer. But it's didn't really answer my question. It seems that much of the current analysis suggests that Hitler was opposed to socialism but the (admittedly translated) transcripts seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: OK, also, this question was in no part about the definition of terms, it was about people using the terms they did. Now the answer may contain reasoning about historic definition of terms and how they differ from today - and that would be the kind of answer I was after (and is based in History, NOT politics)

Comment: Please do not solely reply in comments, but update the question via an [edit] with that info ('no dupe, because…') & any clarifications/refinements. [Note "to get the popular *vote*"? in 1943?]

Comment: Actually LangLangC - reading further into some of the material that was mentioned in that answer has given me a satisfactory answer - thanks. Feel free to close this question - especially if you think the tone is off (....?!)

Comment: I had the same first and second reactions. Perhaps an edit to that question's title might be in order...